# Meteor method call - wait for method to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am really struggling with Meteor callbacks.  I have a client side call to a server side method, but when the callback comes back from the server, I get an undefined result.  As far as I can tell, this is because the server is not finished doing the POST but is already sending the callback.  I am new to Meteor and this seems really difficult.  What I have so far:

Client:

```
Meteor.call("createCustomer", city, fname, lname, email, function(error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("error: " + error);
  } else {
    console.log("result: " + result)
  }
});
```

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'createCustomer': function(city, fname, lname, email) {
    HTTP.call("POST", url+'/customer?api_key='+process.env.API_TOKEN ,{
      data: {
        city: city,
        first_name: fnam,
        last_name: lname,
        email: email
      }
    }, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        return 'error';
      } else {
        return'success';
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I might be doing something really stupid, or it might be more complex than I had anticipated, but any help would go a long way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `Meteor.wrapAsync` is for. It creates a synchronous version of an asynchronous function. Try this:

```js
'createCustomer': function(city, fname, lname, email) {
  var call = Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.call, HTTP);
  return call("POST", url+'/customer?api_key='+process.env.API_TOKEN ,{
    data: {
      city: city,
      first_name: fname,
      last_name: lname,
      email: email
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @PsydeStep there is actually no need to warp it in async. If you don't pass `asyncCallback`, `HTTP.call` runs synchronously. [Read `asyncCallback` description.](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call)

Comment: @RamilMuratov thanks for the insight.  Which is the proper way of doing this, considering Waiski's way worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my original comment.

On the server if you don't pass callback, `HTTP.call` runs synchronously, and no need to use `Meteor.wrapAsync`.

```js
Meteor.methods({
  createCustomer(city, first_name, last_name, email) {
    return HTTP.post(`${url}/customer?api_key=${process.env.API_TOKEN}`, {
      data: { city, first_name, last_name, email }
    });
  }
});
```